# Neo4j browser no more working

Tags: neo4j

I had to reboot my machine during a Neo4j operation because it was slow. Now Neo4j browser: http://localhost:7474/browser/ does not launch anymore
Please how to fix it

Comment: After uninstalling and reinstalling the neo4j package the problem has been solved

Answer (score 0):

The possibility is Neo4j server not running.

Navigate to the **neo4j/bin** folder using command prompt and use below command to start the server.

**./neo4j start**

You can use below parameters -

- status : to know the status of the server.
- restart : to restart the server
- stop : to stop the server.